# Solving max/min problem for graphs based on Grover

Tags: grovers-algorithm, optimization, oracles, graph-states

Basis is for this post ist the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.00445.pdf

I want to do something similar using graph data encoded in quantum states. The circuit structure should look like this (first Grover iteration incl. the oracle):

[image]

- `GDB` stands for a "Graph-Database", meaning a QRAM so that the qubits $|Graph\rangle$ encode some kind of graph in `m` qubits. These states represent the *adjacency matrix* and the *edge weights*.
- $|\psi_1\rangle$ (see the red vertical line) looks like (assuming `n=2` so 4 different graphs): [image]
- $GDB^\dagger$ uncomputes the Graph-Database and the gate `Grover` stands for the usual "inversion about average"
- The big "marking"-gate in middle is my question mark! Let me skip that for now.
- The entire algorithm involves more than one iteration to update the threshold used in the marking-gate accordingly (see the paper). Finally, the `Index` of the graph that satisfies some kind of maximum or minimum requirement among all graphs should be measured with high probability, as usual in the amplitude amplification algorithm (Grover).

## Question

Now the actual question is a bit strange, I admit. Can anyone image a graph-related problem where such a circuit could be useful, that is, what exactly could I do in the marking-gate? Any suggestion is welcome. It may be far from a real usecase. The key point is really to use the graph-encoding.

#### Edit 1

There are, of course, a number of "workspace" qubits that are not shown in the circuit above.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous possibilities.

A straightforward and commonly utilized concept is the generation of Hamiltonian cycles on a complete graph where the vertices symbolize cities, and edges represent distances.

In such a scenario, an oracle calculates the total weight of edges for each generated Hamiltonian cycle and then marks the index of a cycle whose total weight falls below a predetermined threshold. In essence, this approach attempts to solve a Travelling Salesman Problem by examining numerous Hamiltonian cycles and marking the less "expensive" ones in a superposition.

Another widely recognized problem in this realm is MaxCut. In this case, the index register provides guidance to GDB on how to partition the vertices of a graph. Subsequently, the oracle highlights the graph whose cut size exceeds a certain threshold. For example, if the index is $|9\rangle = |1001\rangle$, then vertices $v_1,v_4$ would be in partition $A$, and $v_2, v_3$ would be in partition $B$. The oracle then calculates the edges between partitions $A$ and $B$ (the cut) and computes its size. If the size surpasses the threshold, it is marked.

These are just a couple of examples.

Comment: I probably didn't make myself clear enough. I know about the Hamiltonian cycle and MaxCut problem, but those are problems on **one single** graph. However, I am interested in a problem where **multiple** graphs are candidates for a solution (see again $|\psi_1\rangle$). Of course one could construct a two-step process like: 1. Solve a single-graph-problem like TSP for each graph. 2. Find the minimum value among those solutions. But is there also perhaps a problem that is more obvious that I'm not seeing right now?